# How can I create an ArrayList and automatically assign variables to the drawn Galaga ship? Also to get it to move with arrow keys?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

My current code is listed at the very bottom. So far i have gotten to draw the galaga ship as i would want it to look in the final edition, as well as the stars that appear at random. Now, the only problem, or thing i need to figure out, is how to create an array list, for example:

```
arrayList = new Arraylist()
```

Where the new arrayList has sets of variables assigned to it, as well as in regards to the g.drawLine method. Basically assigning an arraylist variables (x1,y1,x2,y2), and the basic idea is that all the given lines are assigned to this array. Also, to make it actually move, i would use an if() loop, where if("Up" is pressed), then y1+=5; and y2+=5; so it'll move up, as well as other else if loops where "Right", "Left", and "Down" arows are used.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Galaga extends Applet
{
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    DrawBackground(g);
    DrawGalaga(g);
}
public void DrawBackground(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(1,2,3000,4000);
    DrawStars(g);
}
public void DrawGalaga(Graphics g)
{       
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawLine(42,75,42,80); //Far Left Gun
    g.drawLine(43,75,43,80);
    g.drawLine(44,75,44,80);
    g.drawLine(45,75,45,80);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawLine(42,80,42,100); //Far Left Piece
    g.drawLine(43,80,43,100);
    g.drawLine(44,80,44,100);
    g.drawLine(45,80,45,100);

    g.drawLine(46,83,46,96); //From Left, 1st one
    g.drawLine(47,83,47,96);
    g.drawLine(48,83,48,96);
    g.drawLine(49,83,49,96);

    g.drawLine(50,79,50,92); //From Left, 2nd one
    g.drawLine(51,79,51,92);
    g.drawLine(52,79,52,92);
    g.drawLine(53,79,53,92);    

    g.drawLine(54,65,54,89); //From Left, 3rd one
    g.drawLine(55,65,55,89);
    g.drawLine(56,65,56,89);
    g.drawLine(57,65,57,89);

    g.drawLine(58,75,58,89); //From Middle 3rd one
    g.drawLine(59,75,59,89);
    g.drawLine(60,75,60,89);
    g.drawLine(61,75,61,89);

    g.drawLine(62,70,62,85); //From Middle, 2nd Left one
    g.drawLine(63,70,63,85);
    g.drawLine(64,70,64,85);
    g.drawLine(65,70,65,85);

    g.drawLine(66,60,66,95); //From Middle, 1st Left one
    g.drawLine(67,60,67,95);
    g.drawLine(68,60,68,95);
    g.drawLine(69,60,69,95);

    g.drawLine(70,45,70,100); //Big Middle Piece
    g.drawLine(71,45,71,100);
    g.drawLine(72,45,72,100);
    g.drawLine(73,45,73,100);
    g.drawLine(74,45,74,100);
    g.drawLine(75,45,75,100);
    g.drawLine(76,45,76,100);

    g.drawLine(77,60,77,95); //From Middle, 1st Right one
    g.drawLine(78,60,78,95);
    g.drawLine(79,60,79,95);
    g.drawLine(80,60,80,95);

    g.drawLine(81,70,81,85); //From Middle, 2nd Right one
    g.drawLine(82,70,82,85);
    g.drawLine(83,70,83,85);
    g.drawLine(84,70,84,85);

    g.drawLine(85,75,85,89); //From Middle 3rd one
    g.drawLine(86,75,86,89);
    g.drawLine(87,75,87,89);
    g.drawLine(88,75,88,89);

    g.drawLine(88,65,88,89); //From Right, 3rd one
    g.drawLine(89,65,89,89);
    g.drawLine(90,65,90,89);
    g.drawLine(91,65,91,89);

    g.drawLine(92,79,92,92); //From Right, 2nd one
    g.drawLine(93,79,93,92);
    g.drawLine(94,79,94,92);
    g.drawLine(95,79,95,92);

    g.drawLine(96,83,96,96); //From Right, 1st one
    g.drawLine(97,83,97,96);
    g.drawLine(98,83,98,96);
    g.drawLine(99,83,99,96);

    g.drawLine(100,80,100,100); //Far Right Piece
    g.drawLine(101,80,101,100);
    g.drawLine(102,80,102,100);
    g.drawLine(103,80,103,100);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawLine(100,75,100,80); //Far Right Gun
    g.drawLine(101,75,101,80);
    g.drawLine(102,75,102,80);
    g.drawLine(103,75,103,80);
}

public void DrawStars(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    int x, y;
    for (int s = 0; s < 2000; s++) 
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random()*2000);
            y = (int)(Math.random()*2000); 
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
}
public void delay(int n)
{
    long startDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endDelay = 0;
    while (endDelay - startDelay < n)
        endDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but there is one thing you need to utilize.  Using an array to store the X,Y values of each line is a great idea.  The second part though, about changing these values is incorrect.  With 2d and 3d graphics, your model should not change, unless it is being animated.  this means that your array values would not change.  To move the ship, including position, rotation, and sheer,  you use transforms on the graphics object.

Check out this tutorial to understand what I'm talking about.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

as for storing your x1, x2, y1, y2 values, you could create another class.

```
public class MyLine
{
    public final int x1;
    public final int x2;
    public final int y1;
    public final int y2;
    public MyLine(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
    {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }
}
```

Then you can use array list as follows

```
List<MyLine> myLineList = new ArrayList<MyLine>();

myLineList.add(new MyLine(1,2,3,4)); //add as many lines as you'd like.
```

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't look to good to be honest.

First, use some objects instead of implicit roles of array offsets.

```
List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

Now each array element is a valid line. You probably should want to refactor the code even more, couple line with its color etc.

Coming back to your question: don't copy the array, store the ship's points read-only and manipulate x,y offsets.

```
public void DrawGalaga(Graphics g)
{       
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawLine(X0+42,Y0+75,X0+42,Y0+80);
    ...
}
```

where `X0` and `Y0` are the offsets to point `(0,0)`. Then write an event handler:

```
void moveUp(int dx, int dy) { X0 += dx; Y0 += dy; }
```

Watch out for multi-threaded access to `X0` and `Y0`.

Comment: The way you describe would be very difficult to do things such as sheer, and rotations.  The best way to move the ship is to set the AffineTransform on the graphics object.  Using offsets would be viable for things such as arbitrary lines, but not models such as a ship.

Comment: I agree, but the OP didn't ask for such transforms!

Comment: True, but I like to try to steer people in the correct direction.  Sometimes people need an answer to a question they didn't even ask yet =P